# Part of the theorem: "A language is Turing-recognizable if and only if some enumerator enumerates it"

Tags: computation-theory

I need help to understand this proof.

- "First we show that if we have an enumerator E that enumerates a
  language A, a TM M recognizes A. The TM M works in the following way.
- PROOF M = "On input w:
- 1.Run E. Every time that E outputs a string, compare it with w.
- 2. If w ever appears in the output of E, accept."
- Clearly, M accepts those strings that appear on E's list. "

If w doesn't appear in the output of E it doesn't appear in the E's list.
What is he triyng to say?

Comment: Might consider also asking here:   http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theorem has two directions: if the "if" and the "only if". The proof is for the "if" direction.

Assuming you have an enumerator *E* for a language *L*, can you construct a Turing machine *M* that recognizes *L*? Yes, you can. Just define a Turing machine *M* that, on input string *w*, checks to see if *w* is ever in the output of *E* (which may be infinite). If it is, **accept**. If it isn't **reject**.

Since *E* is an enumerator for *L*, for any *w* in *L*, *E* eventually outputs *w* before halting (if it ever halts). Thus, *M* halts for every string in *L*. If *w* is not in L, either *M* never halts, or *M* rejects *w*.

Also, for *M* to be a decider, not just a recognizer for *L*, *M* must *always* halt.

Answer (score 3):

You have to prove both parts since it includes "if and only if" phrase.

First, you should show that if there exists an enumerator E which enumerates all strings in the language L, we can construct a recognizer for this language L.

This recognizer works with an input w ( a string ) and runs the E inside. E is an enumerator which generates all strings in L one by one. If the input string is equal to one of these generated strings then ACCEPT. If this language is infinite, then the recognizer may not halt, which is not a problem for a recognizer since it is not a decider.

Second part is, if L is Turing recognizable then there must be a Turing Machine M that recognizes L. An enumerator can be constructed as follows;

```
for k=1,2,3...
    Run M on w1,w2,w3... in parallelized for k steps
        if M accepts any of the wi then print wi on the printer.
```

The reason why we run them in parallelized with limited steps is the same reason why we prefer depth-limited search over depth-first search. It can go through an infinite dead path on the search graph.